# Can't change background colour on a view..?

Tags: java, android, view

I apologize if this is a blatant mistake on my part, I'm new to Android development..

From the main .java code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_colour);
        View picker = (View) findViewById(R.id.picker);
        picker.setBackgroundColor(0x00FF00);
    }
```

I wouldn't normally have the picker code in the onCreate call, this is simply to be sure it WAS getting executed.

And the picker view is defined in my activity layout .xml

```
    <View
            android:id="@+id/picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/red"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

From what I've read, it would seem findViewById returns a reference to the view, so I should be able to make calls that will affect the original object. As far as I know the setBackgroundColor() method doesn't look like the culprit either so where did I mess up?

Comment: since your are testing try to add width and height to your view such as 100dp. it seems that android chooses 0dp as default size if you don't assign drawable.

Comment: Set a fixed 200x200dp size.. I've tried just now to set a background colour for the view directly in the xml file. It'll look like it should when I look at the layout view within eclipse but when I launch it on the AVD it's still showing up blank.

Edit: I set a different background colour and clearly the view isn't there.. so it's a matter of the view not showing up at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you do not define the alpha, 00 is assumed. try do specifically set it.

```
picker.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

Comment: Oh man I hadn't even thought it might be reading it as argb. Good call, that fixed it! Thanks.